# Learning Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm going to be given ownership of some win32 applications written mostly in unmanaged Visual C++. I have seen the code and obviously many things looked unfamiliar like __stdcall, __deref_out, etc.

I am a .NET developer (mostly using C# and VB). I am familiar with the standard C++ too. What is the best way to learn Visual C++ based on my background?

Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194519/good-book-for-learning-native-visual-c
The responses to that thread focus on Win32 programming instead of Visual C++. Plus, I don't know if VC++ should be learned along with Win32 programming.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Praveen: To prevent this question from being closed, I recommend making your question more specific, perhaps on the order of something more like: "What are the most significant ways in which Visual C++ differs from typical C++", although even that is badly defined.

Comment: What do you perceive to be the difference between Visual C++ and "standard C++"? VC++ is a compiler for standard C++, as well as for C and C++/CLI -- are you actually referring to C++/CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're "familiar with standard C++", then you should be ok with your Visual C++ projects, but expect to do a LOT more learning as you uncover edge cases.

Those double-underscore keywords are implementation-defined extensions to the language, and in Visual C++, you must be aware of different calling conventions, and how to export symbols.

Calling conventions are described here (amongst other places): http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/MSCallingConventions/